# How to create a list of objects from single object in object of IList

Tags: f#

So assume that I have `List<'a>` and inside `'a` there is `'b`

Something like this

```
 type objectA = {
    objectB : object 
 }
```

and I want `List<objectB>`

Is there a F# way of doing this?

I tried using fold and reduce but they both want me to return type `objectA`

I guess what I'm trying to say is I want to make this iterate over all of my `objectA` objects and return a collection of their `objectB` objects. Also I want to do this in a manner that's acceptable in F#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.map%5B't%2C'u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) will allow you to get the list of objectB values:

```
let input : objectA list = [ { objectB = 123 }; { objectB = "foo" }]

let objectBs = List.map (fun a -> a.objectB) input

printfn "%O" objectBs
// yields: [123; foo]
```